# Como agregar un estado resultado de una funcion al submit en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

tengo una funcion que se encarga de leer el contenido de un excel y lo carga en un state. El problema surge cuando quiero que el resultado de esa funcion sea enviado en el fetch del submit.

```
    import {useState} from 'react'
    import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

export const useExcel = () => {

  const [excelItems, setExcelItems] = useState ([]);
    const handleExcel = (file) => {
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          fileReader.onload = (e) => {
            const bufferArray = e.target.result;
            const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });
            var excelData = {};
           // const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
           for (var i = 0; i < wb.SheetNames.length; ++i) {
            let wsname = wb.SheetNames[i];
            console.log(wsname)
            const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
            const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws); 
            excelData[wsname] = jsonData;
          }
    
          resolve(excelData);
        };
    
          fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
            reject(error);
          };
        });
    
        promise.then((d) => {
          setExcelItems(d);
          console.log(excelItems);
          
        });
      };
      
return {
handleExcel,
excelItems
}
};
```

este seria el .js del useForm que controla los datos ingresados en un form

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import { useExcelReader } from './useExcelReader';

export const useForm = (initialForm, validateForm) => {
const [form, setForm] = useState (initialForm);
const [errors, setErrors] = useState ({});
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [response, setResponse] = useState (null);
const [excelItems, setExcelItems] = useState ([]);

const handleChange = (e, handleExcel) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    
    if(name === "file"){
      setExcelItems(handleExcel(value));
      console.log(excelItems); 
    }else{
    setForm({
        ...form,
        [name]:value,
    });}
}

const handleBlur = (e) => {
 handleChange(e);
 setErrors(validateForm(form));
 
}


const handleSubmit = (e, excelItems) => {
  var file = excelItems;
  var preguntas = Object.values(file.Preguntas);
  var materias = Object.values(file.Materias);
  var plantaDocente =  Object.values(file['Planta Docente']);

    console.log(form);
    setErrors(validateForm(form));
    var url = ' https://services-dev.ufasta.edu.ar/apps/encuestas/insertar/encuesta';
    var jsonData = (form, preguntas, materias, plantaDocente);
    
    alert("Enviando Formulario")
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        body: jsonData, // data can be `string` or {object}!
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(res => res.json())
      .catch(error => alert('Error:', error))
      .then(response => alert('Success:', response));
      
}


return {
form, 
errors, 
loading, 
response, 
handleChange, 
handleBlur, 
handleSubmit
}

};
```

No estaria comprendiendo como enviar ese valor por separado al contenido del form, aunque tambien necesito que este controlado por react.

el problema mas grave es el mencionado, pero si tienen alguna sugerencia mas es bienvenida.
Desde ya Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por lo que veo `excelItems` se define en el component `useExcel` y no está disponible en `useForm`. Lo que puedes hacer para que `excelItems` sea accesible es pasarla como un prop adicional en el método `handleSubmit`.

```
const handleSubmit = (e, excelItems) => {
  var jsonData = (form, excelItems, preguntas, materias, plantaDocente);
}
```

Y ya donde llamas a `useForm` pasas `excelItems` como argumento en `handleSubmit`.

```
const { form, errors, loading, response, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit } = useForm(initialForm, validateForm);

<form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e, excelItems)}>
  {/* Aquí van los campos del formulario */}
</form>
```

Comment: Genial, por suerte pude resolver el inconveniente. Exactamente como me mencionaste. Muchas gracias!